# react and flow: import Node type and PureComponent in one line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, flowtype

How to import `Node` (type used by flow), and `PureComponent` in one line only for code purity.

Lines below don't work:

```
import type { Node }, { PureComponent } from 'react';
// or
import type { Node, PureComponent } from 'react';
```

Note: I actually use this

```
/* @flow */
import { PureComponent } from 'react';
import type { Node } from 'react';
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure `Node` is part of `react` package?

Comment: @ArnoldGandarillas I added lines that actually work. If found the `Node` import [here](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/website/en/docs/react/types.md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the docs mentioned [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/), for using the named type import, you need to add in addition to the default import.

Again, if you `import React with: import React from 'react'` you will be able to access `React.Component, React.createElement(), React.Children,` and other JavaScript values. However, you will not be able to access `React.Node, React.ChildrenArray` or other `Flow types.` You will need to use a named type `import like: import type {Node} from 'react'` in addition to your `default import.`

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
import { type Node, PureComponent } from 'react';
```

Which works and is clean.